# Jenkins stops at Launching Internet Explorer

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration, jenkins

we are using Jenkins as CI in our project. We were running the CI from the command line using the following command

```
java -jar C:\\jenkins\\jenkins.war --httpPort=8085 --ajp13Port=8009
```

As the system needs to restart frequently, we change CI to start as a windows service.

Now we are facing the issues for Selenium test cases. Selenium test cases are not running after we make Jenkins as service. We are getting the following log and no more progress from that point

```
18:36:30,718 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler] Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*iexploreproxy, http://192.168.132.105:8080/, ] on session null
18:36:30,718 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory] creating new remote session
18:36:30,796 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory] Allocated session 80b95d0273ac4ea4a82860c79438f071 for http://192.168.132.105:8080/, launching...
18:36:30,796 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.WindowsProxyManager] Modifying registry settings...
18:36:31,781 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.InternetExplorerCustomProxyLauncher] Launching Internet Explorer...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following changes will resolve the problem

1. Update the selenium version.
2. Use *iexploreproxy or *piiexplore for IE instead of *iehta/*iexplore

Answer (score 0):

Per hudson wiki, you should be running Hudson (or jenkins) as tasks rather than service for GUI testing. Check [here](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Tomcat). Look at the section GUI Testing in Windows